# International Travel with a wireless kit?

Tags: wireless, kit, frequency

Hi guys!
I'm looking to buy a wireless mic kit to use for on location recording for a upcoming documentary.

The problem is that this docu is going to be shot in different locations all over the world. I will be going to India, Indonesia, Europe and America.

I have been looking at the Sennheiser EW100 G3 series but am also considering a lectrosonics kit. But I am totally confused by which frequency block to get.

Any advice?

Are there multi frequencies devices out there?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I went through the same problem. I do a lot of documentary, and therefore I'm in various countries requiring different blocks.

Forgetting about the legal aspect of things, all blocks should work in most places. You might  get a bit more RF interference in some countries, but within the range of one of the blocks from the EW100 G3 series, you should be able to find a clean frequency.

If you're buying a few, I recommend splitting them up, so getting for example one A, one B and one G. If you can't, you should be safe with either. The stricter countries (I think) are the US and the UK so if you stick to the ones okay there, you should be fine. Just don't get block 28.

Just make sure you get one that works in your country of origine, or where you work the most so you don't have to sell it after the gig.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Add Japan to that strict list too, though if you can get it pass customs, you'll be fine. What some of my friends doing docus do is to pool their wireless sets together and get different blocks. If they're traveling to a different country, they simply exchange the sets.

Comment: @Tak oh wow, they'll stop you at customs... That's hectic! What a great idea to pool your wireless systems! 

Comment: @ Andrew Spitz Thanks for your reply. Im just going to buy a frequency block and hope it works! Might have to rent one when in Europe though.